# How to add click event listener on ol.control in Openlayers 4?

Tags: angular, openlayers

I'm trying to log UI-interactions and therefore I'd like to get click/tab events from my `ol.controls` (`ol.control.Zoom`, `ol.control.Rotate`, `ol.control.Attribution`).

But how? I cannot find anything in the [docs](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.control.html)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find then either but I may missed the point too.
You may forget using OpenLayers API in particular and use pure JavaScript.

```
// Check zoom +/- buttons event
document.querySelector('.ol-zoom').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  if (evt.target.classList.contains('ol-zoom-in')) {
    console.log('Zoom in');
  } else if (evt.target.classList.contains('ol-zoom-out')) {
    console.log('Zoom out');
  }
});

// Check if rotate button clicked (normally visible only if map rotated)
document.querySelector('.ol-rotate').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  console.log('Rotate');
});

// Check if attribution button opened or closed
document.querySelector('.ol-attribution').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  if (evt.currentTarget.classList.contains('ol-collapsed')) {
    console.log('Collapsed');
  } else {
    console.log('Opened');
  }
});
```

If you want to observe events from OpenLayers without a concern for where the click happened (because a zoom event can be generated by a mouse wheel, a double click on the map or a click on +/- zoom button), you may want to listen on `ol.View` events

```
map.getView().on('change:rotation', evt => {
  console.log('Rotation event', evt);
})

map.getView().on('change:resolution', evt => {
  console.log('Resolution event', evt);
})
```

PS: There are others events you can listen on the view but I let you inspect them in the API

Comment: thx for pointing that out. I already thought about using pure JS. I just wanted to be sure there is no built-in event handling for `ol.controls`